Expectation of Changes in Top K Elements Amongst Randomly Generated Numbers
I am conducting a Monte Carlo simulation where:

I generate n random numbers uniformly.
Select the top k of these numbers.
Then regenerate c of the n numbers at random.

I aim to compute the mean number of entries in the top k set that are dropped due to these changes (or equivalently: the mean number of new numbers that enter the top k, since for every number that leaves this set, another enters).
I am seeking a mathematical formulation, rather than a simulation, to compute the expected number of entries dropped and new entries given the parameters.
To illustrate, here is a simplified example:

Start with n=5 numbers: [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9].
Choose the top k=3 numbers: [0.5, 0.7, 0.9].
Regenerate c=2 numbers to get: [0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9].
The new top 3 numbers are [0.7, 0.8, 0.9].

The number 0.5 (not regenerated) has dropped from the top k, and 0.8 (regenerated) has entered.
Here's my code that could be used for validation:
from typing import Tuple

import numpy as np

def simulate_top_k_change(n: int, k: int, c: int, trials: int = 1000000) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    changes_in_top_k = []

    for _ in range(trials):
        # Generate n random numbers between 0 and 1
        numbers = np.random.rand(n)

        # Find indices of the top k numbers
        original_top_indices = np.argpartition(numbers, -k)[-k:]
        original_top_set = set(original_top_indices)

        # Randomly select c numbers to regenerate
        indices_to_regenerate = np.random.choice(n, c, replace=False)

        # Regenerate c random numbers
        numbers[indices_to_regenerate] = np.random.rand(c)

        # Find new top k numbers
        new_top_indices = np.argpartition(numbers, -k)[-k:]
        new_top_set = set(new_top_indices)

        # Calculate the change in the top k set
        pushed_out = len(original_top_set - new_top_set)  # In original but not in new
        new_entries = len(new_top_set - original_top_set)  # In new but not in original

        changes_in_top_k.append((pushed_out, new_entries))

    # Compute average changes
    avg_pushed_out = np.mean([change[0] for change in changes_in_top_k])
    avg_new_entries = np.mean([change[1] for change in changes_in_top_k])

    return avg_pushed_out, avg_new_entries


# Example parameters
# n = 100  # total numbers
# k = 10  # top numbers to choose
# c = 5  # numbers to regenerate

n = 5
k = 3
c = 2
# (0.65716, 0.65716)

print(simulate_top_k_change(n, k, c))

For n=5, k=3, c=2 it gives me ~0.65716 changes over 1m trials.
Does someone have some guidance on how to approach this?
